# discord bot saves a text file attachement that user sends

Tags: python, discord.py

i am making a bot that downloads the text files sent from users to gather some data
is it possible to download those files or save them?
i am using Pycharm

Comment: You can indeed store text in a JSON for example.

Answer (score 0):

You could go by using [message.attachments](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=attachments#discord.Message.attachments) and using [save()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=attachments#discord.Attachment.save):

`await message.attachments[0].save()`

Then reading the file which can be done by using `open(message.attachments[0].filename, "r")` unless you use another file name then you can read it and store it in a JSON file or even a database.

Comment: is there a way to read the message without saving it locally?

Comment: @AXEL you could try to use .read() and maybe use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string